# List the log files created on a specific day

Tags: linux, shell

I want to list the latest file which was created on sunday . I jus want the files which are created at a specific time on only sundays (for eg : 12:30 am on sunday )

Answer (score 0):

To show all files created on 26/02/2018:
sudo find / -type f -newermt 2018-02-26

Comment: The date should not be hardcoded . it should find the latest sunday file dynamically\